# how to check if int input is empty or user pushed enter key in a while loop C++

Tags: c++

i made 3n+1 problem on UVA (ID:100) but i cant break out of the input loop
what can i do to check if the input is empty or user clicked enter?

the loop is like this

```
  int i,j;
  while(cin>>i>>j){

  //LOOP BODY
 }
```

how can i terminate/break if user clicked enter?

Comment: Use `std::getline()` in first place.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just do

```
int i,j;
std::string line;
  while(std::getline(cin,line) && !line.empty()){
      std::istringstream iss(line);
      if(iss >>i>>j) {
         //LOOP BODY
      }
 }
```

Comment: I fail to understand why people downvote without leaving a comment.

Comment: @RSahu Probably because I answered a not so well achieved question, the answer is deemed to be unuseful as well.